# jQuery: is there a way for tablesorterPager to show selectable page numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, tablesorter

I'm using jQuery TableSorter and i'm trying to add page navigation (withing the tablesorter).
Now tablesorter has a pager plugin, but the problem is it doesn't show the page numbers, so you can't select a specific page to view.

I found this Pagination plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination which is exactly what i'm looking for. problem is, all attempts made by me trying to combine the tow gave me lots of errors..

Is there a way to combine them? or maybe alter tablesorterPager so it will be able to select pages?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to alter the TablesorterPager. Two plugins modifying a single DOM element can get messy. The code would be easy to add in the plugin assuming that you have experience with authoring jQuery plugins. If not, I'll give you a brief outline and if you can't figure it out I'd be more than happy to help further.

- Create a function to set up a `<ul>` with a `<li>` for each page number. You can choose to hide the middle few like this website does, or not.
- Call this function from the constructor
- Set a click() event in the constructor to load the page. The easiest way I think to do this would be to simply have each `<li>` have an ID of something along the lines of #page0, #page1, #page2, etc. That way you can just strip the 'page' part, and send them to the page based on the .val() of the item they clicked on.
- While you're changing the page, you'll probably want to toggle some active classes and possible alter the original `<ul>` children. This could all be wrapped into a function. Specifics on what elements to alter and what the class names are will be found in the plugin add-on.

Good luck! Post a comment or something if you would like further detail.